# touchscreen on tablet not working when running ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen, tablet

I have an insignia flex 8 8 inch tablet that currently runs windows 10. I got a ubuntu 18.04LTS desktop live usb to boot and discovered that everything runs well except for the touchscreen. I plan on dual booting this tablet. There is very little info online for windows drivers and fudge all when it comes to linux info on this tablet.

My question is:

1: How can I get the touchscreen to work

The make and model of the tablet is an insignia NS-P08W7100C.

The touchscreen controller is a KMDF HID Minidriver for Touch I2C Device

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I seem to have the same issue with a slightly different tablet but the same screen.

Comment: @jkt123 I haven't been able to find anything yet in regards to drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Vonino tablet with same KMDF HID Minidriver for Touch I2C Device, touchscreen is working with this driver https://github.com/edward-p/mssl1680-firmware/ but i still have problems with calibration....